# Is installing PHP on Cygwin just like it being on a real Linux server?

Tags: php, linux, unix, cygwin

I currently use XAMPP on Windows 7 for my dev server which is a LAMP stack.

I recently installed cygwin and have been messing around with it.  I am just curious, with cygwin since it is like unix/linux does that mean that you can install apache and php just as if you were installing it on a Linux server?  I know you can install them on cygwin as I saw them in a package list but I'm not sure if this is the same as if I was installing it on a real production linux server?

From what I read cygwin mimics unix/linux on windows.

Comment: It's not the same in the sense that you're still running Windows.

Comment: I assume you want to "mimic" the development in some *nix environment.  Why don't you play with vmware instances instead as it will be a 100% Linux box. It works quite well for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It highly depends on your production needs,  but after all cygwin is just an emulation-layer and nothing more. It does an incredible job but its hard for me to believe its hardly as reliable as a Unix box.

You can read more about it in this slashdot thread:
http://ask.slashdot.org/story/04/08/12/1932246/cygwin-in-a-production-environment

Shai.

Comment: Hi, I don't mean to use it in production, I mean as a dev server to develop on in Windows.  Right now I use XAMPP which is like a standalone LAMP setup but I am curious if I can get my LAMP setup going with cygwin and if it is the same as linux (the install process)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can. Haven't tried so myself but if we're just talking on a development environment you should be good.

Answer (score 6):

The old question (and old answers) are still functional these days. However, I thought it'd be worth to add that, right now (June 2017), this became much simpler under Cygwin. Don't know if it has to do with Apache or PHP 7 changing something, but anyway I didn't have to follow lots of tutorials for my initial configuration.

Now it's really just a matter of running Cygwin setup, and selecting packages `httpd`, `php`, `httpd-mod_php7`, `php-mysqli` and `mysql-server` (in fact, some additional dependent packages will also be selected by Cygwin - and it will ask you for your confirmation, as you might already know).

When you next go to Cygwin console, you just need to `apachectl start`, and there it is readily available on port 80. If you need it as an all-time available server, configuring server is still the same with `cygserver-config`.

No `apt-cyg` needed, or importing packages from Cygwin Ports - although it's also great and still works beautifully. It just became a bit simpler.

Answer (score 5):

**Install cygwin**

with the following packages:

1. gawk, (default install)
2. tar, (default install)
3. bzip2, (default install)
4. wget,
5. subversion,
6. mail,
7. sSMTP,
8. util-linux,
9. ncurses,
10. openSSH,
11. cygrunsrv,
12. apache2
13. and MySQL
14. **apt-cyg**

**Install php**

install PHP using:

```
apt-cyg -m ftp://ftp.cygwinports.org/pub/cygwinports/ install php
```

and also

```
apache2-mod_php5
php-mysql
php-mysqli
php-PEAR
```

**Configuring Servers**

```
/usr/bin/cygserver-config
```