# Is it possible to fully simulate linux web server on windows machine with cygwin?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, cygwin

This is a theoretical question and hope you won't refuse it directly.

The problem I am having is that I am working both on front-end and back-end development. Basically by day I am fron-end developer which involves a lot of different browsers, Photoshop and other tools needed for design/fron-end work. But by night I am heavy php developer.

Now this is quite a tricky situation. As a back-end developer I would really love to use linux server, same as production servers for projects, which will be much easier to synchronize. But as a front-end developer I need all the tools, that are available mostly for windows.

I have been looking long time for a solution OTHER than virtual linux machine. Finally i ran into the Cygwin. It looks promissing, but my question is, can I fully simulate linux webserver with this tool? are there any limitations?

I would appreciate any opinion, also if you know about some elegant way/tool how to achieve what I need, please share it with me.

Thank you!

EDIT: 
Why I don't want to use virtual machine:

1. It takes too much RAM. If I run IDE, Photoshop, Virtual Machine etc. my PC has hard time to catch UP
2. I am looking for "seamless" solution. Something that can run quietly on my background, best as a service.
3. File sharing. I know it is possible to share files between PC and virtual machine but I just don't feel like it is very elegant solution

I had something more on my mind, but this is what I could come up with so far. 
Basically Linux is pretty amazing, and I just cannot believe there would not be any simplier, less-robust solution to this problem than installing whole linux system.

Comment: explain what you have against the obvious best answer - virtualisation ?  I run windows locally and the work servers are Linux, i have have my ftp app automatically upload my local changes to work dev server, seem to work. so i dont need to run linux locally

Comment: By "web server" do you mean a piece of software that serves web pages? Or do you mean a physical device that serves web pages?

Comment: you wont be able to do it using just windows. if you want to really emulate the server production, you need a virtual machine with the same specs and OS. I use vmware and virtualbox, this last one is free.

Comment: Yes. When you install Cygwin, you can select to install Apache and PHP as well. Then you can edit the files with your native editor. Use `/usr/sbin/apachectl2 start` to start Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wish I could help more, but right from cygwins website it says "Cygwin is not: a way to run native Linux apps on Windows."

That said, it appears some people have [got a lamp stack working in Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806846/how-do-i-install-mysql-on-cygwin) and [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375670/is-installing-php-on-cygwin-just-like-it-being-on-a-real-linux-server)

So it sounds possible, but I have to re ask the question of why you would want to. Seems extraordinarily complex when you could install virtualbox and [a turn key linux solution](http://www.turnkeylinux.org) to get a real environment that is much easier to troubleshoot.

If you do get it working, I'd love to see a blog post on how you got it.

Comment: This is actually fulfilling answer for me. The result is that it might be possible but it would be too much hassle, probably not very stable = no. I guess I will have to stick to my windows server, which is not bad, I am just trying to improve my working environment :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "fully simulate".

You can run an apache web server in cygwin, but [it is quite difficult to set up](http://www.naiksblog.info/shantibhushan/cygwinapachephp.html). By a strict definition of "fully simulate" this is already quite different, the steps to set up the web server are different from a real linux machine.

Given that PHP already abstracts a lot of the underlying system away from you, you might find that there is really very little difference (for most purposes) in going down this path vs just installing [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) for your development.

Rather than install a virtual machine on your dev system you could also get a [free amazon instance](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) (for the first year) and do your web dev on that.

Comment: There is not much point setting up another linux space while I have my own server. THe whole point is to develop locally, when I am out of reach of connection. I travel quite often and not always connected. But nice answer, thank you

Comment: You might like to buy an old Android phone and [install debian on it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyIxDO2vpco). You can use wifi to connect to it and do your development from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Apache with PHP on a windows machine without any hassle at all. You do not even need Cygwin.

I run Apache+PHP and use it for development. I have not had any problems with transferring to a Linux machine. I use [FTP Sync](http://www.cyberkiko.com/page/FTPSync.aspx) to update the Linux machine with just a click on an icon and it just updates the necessary files.

Comment: Im sorry but this is not really helpful. Of course I have apache and php on my windows machine and it works just fine, but not perfect. For example I want to be able to install imagemagick the same, simple way on my pc as on server, I dont want to be adding PATH variable in my windows everytime I want to use some package/extension etc. By the way, I almost NEVER upload development files to the server, everything is going through GIT

Comment: @Tom i want super models to .. .well you cant have everything, you know all the options already, pick one and suck it up

Comment: Surely a little hassle to install external packages to get an environment for development is just a one off exercise. BTW - I also use GIT but I create a pre-install version just to do sanity check before I FTP to the external machine that I do not have command line access to.